# Laravel 5.2 geting Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: laravel-5

2 and I am getting some strange problem I am using model inject in blade for example when I am using this code:

```
 <?php  $b = $model1->where('id', '=', $product->user_id)->first(); ?>

  {{$b->first_name}}
```

I am getting what I want as a result but when I do the same thing wiht this code:

```
 <?php  $b1 = $model2->select('name','number')->where('device_id',  '=', $product->imception_id)->distinct()->first(); ?>
  {{$b1}}
```

This gives me :

```
 {"name":"jan","number":"447515485475"}
```

But when I am doing this :

```
 {{$b1->name}}
```

I am getting Trying to get property of non-object  I don't know how this will work what do I need to do please answer thanks in advance.

Comment: How about defining your model in your controller? Does this give the same result?

Comment: Not possible I don't know one of the code with first thing work but other one is not working and variable shows it is an object. Question how to get that value